# How do I get the navigation to display correctly using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, navigation, bootstrap-4

I am doing some updates to a [site](http://letmagichappen.com/new/) and implementing Bootstrap 4 beta and am having trouble with the navigation displaying correctly. I have been able to finesse some aspects but it is stuck in a vertical display - see attached.

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is the additional css I have applied to get the navigation to show as it now is:

```
.navbar { 
  float: left; 
}

#navbar { 
  display: block; 
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav > li.active { 
  float: left;
}
```

I did the base layout in isolation and the navigation displays correctly but I cannot see what is causing it to fail here. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Bootstrap V3:**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

**For bootstrap v4:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown link
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Else</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <h6 class="dropdown-header">Nav header</h6>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link2</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: When I remove the additional CSS I see a blue box. I don't see what you are seeing.

Comment: Without the additional CSS you see a bluebox? Try to use this code I posted in your file without the extra CSS and see if it is still the same. And make sure your bootstrap files are updated.

Comment: Highdef. That solves one problem but it introduces a whole host of other problems. The navigation appears, but the resource files and the navigation code are all from Bootstrap 3.3.7. I am using Bootstrap 4 and the two are not compatible.

Comment: @fmz Well, the code you posted for the navigation was for bootstrap 3 and that's why it was introducing that styling problem,  you may continue to use bootstrap 4 but you need to change you entire navigation to bootstrap 4 as well.

Comment: Right you are. I had been working back and forth between the two systems and I inadvertently left the version 3 navigation code in there. Thank you.

Comment: @fmz No problem mate :) If you need I can cook up a quick v4 navigation bar for those links and dropdown.

Comment: @fmz Alright, but I updated it either way in case if you need it for reference.If you found it helpful you could upvote :) Cheers

Comment: Followup question: The navigation is now showing correctly on all views, but the button does not display the navigation links on mobile. Any ideas what may be going on here?

Comment: @fmz Are you referring to the dropdown button?

Comment: Yes. If you click on it nothing happens. Although in the inspector you can see that it changes state. I searched extensively on this and there are multiple references. I modified the navigation and it worked briefly, but it no longer drops down.

Comment: Do you have the website hosted somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161319/discussion-between-fmz-and-highdef).